# run /usr/sbin/sshd in a Dockerfile does not work

Tags: docker

In a Dockerfile I wanted to start the ssh daemon, and then give bash:

```
from fedora
run yum -y install openssh-server openssh-clients openssh
run yum clean all
run echo "PermitRootLogin yes">>/etc/ssh/sshd_config
run ssh-keygen -A
run ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
run cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
run /usr/sbin/sshd
expose 22
cmd /usr/bin/bash
```

I create the image and start a container from it,

```
$ sudo docker build -t test/openssh .

$ sudo docker run -it --rm  -P test/openssh
```

But in the container I see that sshd is not running. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RUN` commands in your `Dockerfile` are the bash commands you would use to set up, install and/or configure the software inside your container. This commands will run (and will end) during the docker image building, and any `RUN` command supposed to start a daemon process won't work. They are some patterns to run various processes inside your container when you start it. One of the most common is using [supervisord](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/) (in this official documentation you can see an example using it to run a ssh daemon).

Comment: It works. But now I use systemd instead of supervisord.

Comment: @Javier Cortejoso: could you please update the embedded URL to `supervisord`